# Solving $\int e^{|x|} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Solving $\displaystyle\int e^{|x|} dx$.

I just solved a quite similar *definite* integral, and it wasn't hard, but it was because I could divide the integral in two integrals and get rid of modulus. Problem is I can't do that here, since it's *indefinite* now. I tried already substitution, parts, series and got nothing. How can I aproach such integral?

Thanks.

Edit: I'd like to obtain [Wolfram's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20e%5E%7Cx%7C%20dx) answer, not a function defined by parts.

Comment: You’ll probably have to make use of the of the “sign function” if you want to integrate over positive and negative numbers at once

Comment: yes, that's what I'd like. But I can't see how to properly integrate and make sgn appear.

Comment: @JoelSuvari NB that Wolfram's answer only hides the piecewise definition in the sign function, wich is in itself defined piecewise constant.

Comment: $\int{ \lvert x \rvert} = \frac{1}{2}x^2sgn(x)+c$

Comment: @JosephEck: also written $x|x|/2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us express the antiderivative as a definite integral plus a constant.

$$\int e^{|x|}dx=\int_0^x e^{|x|}dx+C.$$

Then for positive $x$,

$$e^x-1+C$$

and for negative $x$,

$$1-e^{-x}+C.$$

Hence

$$\text{sgn}(x)\left(e^{|x|}-1\right)+C.$$

[image]

As we can check, the derivative is $\text{sgn}^2(x)e^{|x|}$ (and $1$ for $x=0$).

---

Note that WA seemed to strive to avoid the absolute value in the exponent. We can achieve the same effect with

$$\text{sgn}(x)\frac{(1+\text{sgn}(x))(e^x-1)+(1-\text{sgn}(x))(e^{-x}-1)}{2}
=\frac{(\text{sgn}(x)+1)(e^x-1)-(\text{sgn}(x)-1)(e^x-1)e^{-x}}2
=e^{-x}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)(e^x-1)^2+e^{2x}-e^x-e^x-1}2.$$

This is ugly.

Comment: This is actually a good pedagogical example. It clearly shows that the "indefinite integral" operator is dangerous as it easily leads to errors. The "true" operator is the definite integral. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply integrate separately for $x\ge 0$ and $x<0$. The result is then the function defined in different ways for $x\ge 0$ and $x<0$. 
(But it will be actually possible to write it as an unique expression).

Comment: Thanks! My main curiosity is indeed how to get the function Wolfram obtains, which is a unique expression.

Comment: @Joel It is indeed defined in parts, because sign function is. But for obtaining that result, you need to separately integrate and then try to find a way to combine

Comment: Should be tagged as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

The result given by Wolframalpha might seem attractive, but it isn't. Consider
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}((e^x-1)^2\operatorname{sgn}(x)-2e^x+e^{2x}-1)
$$
(the integration constant is irrelevant); then, for $x>0$,
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}(e^{2x}-2e^x+1-2e^x+e^{2x}-1)=
\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}(2e^{2x}-4e^x)=e^x-2
$$
For $x<0$,
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}(-e^{2x}+2e^x-1-2e^x+e^{2x}-1)=-e^{-x}
$$
Also $F(0)=-1$ and it can be easily checked that $F'(x)=e^{|x|}$ for all $x$.

On the other hand, doing algebraic manipulations we obtain
$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{2}((e^x-2+e^{-x})\operatorname{sgn}(x)-2+e^x-e^{-x})
$$
Note that $e^x-e^{-x}=(e^{|x|}-e^{-|x|})\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and that $e^x+e^{-x}=e^{|x|}+e^{-|x|}$, so we obtain
\begin{align}
F(x)
&=\frac{1}{2}((e^{|x|}+e^{-|x|}-2+e^{|x|}-e^{-|x|})\operatorname{sgn}(x)+2) \\[6px]
&=(e^{|x|}-1)\operatorname{sgn}(x)+1
\end{align}
which is much simpler, isn't it?

Answer (score -5):

Write $e^{|x|}=e^{\operatorname{sgn}(x) x}$. Then

$$\int e^{|x|} dx = \int e^{\operatorname{sgn}(x)x} dx = \frac{e^{\operatorname{sgn}(x)x}}{\operatorname{sgn}(x)} + C = \operatorname{sgn}(x)e^{|x|} + C$$

edit: And well, this is broken.

Comment: Oh, nice! An antiderivative of a continuous function which is not continuous!

Comment: @egreg Oh my. I must have broken calculus. Er... I mean my calculus is broken. I'll leave this up. I think it's a valuable incorrect answer.

Comment: @zahbaz: I appreciate your choice of **not** deleting. I am generally against the "deletion mania" of Math.SE, because mathematics is learned through **errors**.